# How to deal with changing network call return structures for JSON object decoding in Swift 4

Tags: json, swift, api, class, struct

I have a struct which is being populated with a returned network object type from a rest based API. The problem I’m encountering is that for certain network calls the returned object may not contain all of the object parameters in the struct and the class does not initialize:

Example:

```
struct Rebate: Codable {
    let categoryID: Int?
    let customerTypes: [RebateCustomerType]?
    let financialInstitution: String
    let financialInstitutionID: Int
    let id: Int
    let identCode: String
    let lenderCode: String
    let maxCreditScore: Int
    let minCreditScore: Int
    let name: String
    let nameDisplay: String
    let number: String
    let receipientType: Int
    let revisionDate: String
    let selected: Bool?
    let startDate: String
    let stopDate: String
    let terms: [Term]?
    let transactionType: Int
    let type: Int
    let updateTS: String
    let value: RebateValue
    let valueType: Int
    let isGeneric: Bool?
    let maxTerm: [MaxTerm]?
```

I’d like to find out how I can ignore, for example, the maxTerm parameter, or any other parameter, if the network call return does not have that data.

Is this even possible?

The API we are using has changing class structures for a number of parameters. This causes the data to not properly parse into a valid class object.

I've searched Stackoverflow without prevail...

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Just make those parameters optional and it will parse

Comment: You already defined `maxTerm`  as an optional property and that's the correct way to approach this

Answer (score 0):

It should parse if you make those parameters optional. But I see you forgot to make parameter **value** optional. Try to make it optional.

Comment: I will try this. Thanks.

Comment: I changed the struct to optionals but I'm still getting no parsed data when a parameter is not found...

lease = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Rebate.self, from: data)
    
lease?.id

lease is nil since it did not parse.

Comment: Check if you didn't forget to make any parameter in LeaseData struct/class optional.

Comment: I'm using "Paste JSON quicktype" to create the class/struct and flip the switch for make all parameters optional. I'm using the most minimalist configuration possible on it. (https://quicktype.io) they also have a macOS app. I checked the struct again. All parameters are optional. Thanks for your help btw.